# How to get modelproperty displayed in asp.net mvc 3 razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display a property from my model. At the moment I cant display the address of the 2 persons on top?

action method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Person person = new Person() {name="Jan Kees",address="Beukenootjes straat 23" };
    Person person2 = new Person() { name = "Peter Jan", address = "Beukenootjes straat 23" };
    List<Person> lijst = new List<Person>();
    lijst.Add(person);
    lijst.Add(person2);

    return View(lijst);
}
```

person class

```
 public class Person
 {
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string address { get; set; }
 }
```

index view

```
@model IEnumerable<stack.Models.Person>

@item.address @*how to display address?*@

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.name <br />
}
```

Comment: @ActiveDan : I would like to display it only once because it is the same address. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display only once you can use

```
@Model.First().address
```

*I want to add more explanation to the code maybe it also help somebody else in similar situations*

this work because your Model is IEnumerable, so to select element you can use Linq, and `First()` get the first element of sequence

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the `@item.address` call within the foreach block:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.name <br />
    @item.address
}
```

You can order it however you need, e.g. address can appear before name.